# I don't have the proper gstreamer dll loaded for C++ opencv camera capture

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I have successfully capture the webcam using Python and opencv but now I am getting back into C++ and trying to do the same simple functionality.

Here's my (trimmed down) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
int main()
{
    Mat img;
    VideoCapture cam(0);
    if (cam.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Camera is opened." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Camera is NOT opened." << endl;
    }
    const string camWin{ "Rufus' Webcam" };
    namedWindow(camWin);
    while (1) {
        cam >> img;
        imshow(camWin, img);
        if (waitKey(1) == 27)
            break;
    }
    cam.release();
}
```

This is the error I get when I run:

> attempting to open the camera using opencv.
> [ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\videoio_registry.cpp (191) cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(7, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940)
> [ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (370) cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER
> [ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (175) cv::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\rufuss\source\repos\OpenCVinCPP\x64\Debug\opencv_videoio_gstreamer450_64d.dll => FAILED
> [ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (175) cv::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_gstreamer450_64d.dll => FAILED
> [ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (370) cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for MSMF
> [ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (175) cv::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\rufuss\source\repos\OpenCVinCPP\x64\Debug\opencv_videoio_msmf450_64d.dll => OK
> [ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (236) cv::impl::PluginBackend::PluginBackend Video I/O: loaded plugin 'Microsoft Media Foundation OpenCV Video I/O plugin'
> Camera is opened.

(basically it doesn't find: opencv_videoio_gstreamer450_64d.dll, because it doesn't exist, so not a path problem)

I could use some help either:

1. Installing the missing dll:  opencv_videoio_gstreamer450_64d.dll properly.
   or
2. Disabling gstreamer from the opencv search list.

Either would help me, but I'd actually like to know both techniques, for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try adding `cam.open(0, CAP_DSHOW);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
int main()
{
    Mat img;
    VideoCapture cam;
    cam.open(0, CAP_DSHOW);
    if (cam.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Camera is opened." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Camera is NOT opened." << endl;
    }
    const string camWin{ "Rufus' Webcam" };
    namedWindow(camWin);
    while (1) {
        cam >> img;
        imshow(camWin, img);
        if (waitKey(1) == 27)
            break;
    }
    cam.release();
}
```

If you would like to learn more please see [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html).

Also you could do cmake `-DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF` while building, to disable gstreamer. (see [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/100666/how-to-build-opencv-2413-without-gstreamer/))

Comment: I started working on rebuilding.  I was originally trying to go with prebuilt binaries...

Comment: After muddling a bit, deleting all opencv instances, double checking my includes and dependencies, copying my dlls from the prebuilt windows opencv binaries I was able to get the DSHOW version going.  I assume gstreamer is preferable, but I haven't figured out how to install/build gstreamer for opencv, even though my other (python) apps seem to have a version in the envrionment modules....  But at least I'm able to capture the webcam now.  I'll keep pressing on with the painful learning....

Comment: It's good to hear that! :) I am not sure if it help with your problem but to build opencv w/ gstreamer you may also see https://galaktyk.medium.com/how-to-build-opencv-with-gstreamer-b11668fa09c

Comment: Thanks for that link - it looks like a good process, but the "two hours later..." image weren't encouraging.  When I feel adventurous, I'll try.  Then I'll feed it back here.